# How to Deploy Spring Cloud Function to AWS lambda continuously

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, continuous-integration, spring-cloud-function

Is it possible to deploy Spring Cloud function to AWS Lambda Continuously.

I want to use gradle and  bitbucket pipeline, or if there is any effective way I can use.

Should I use '@EnableFunctionDeployer' annotation? What is the best way?

Answer (score 2):

`@EnableFunctionDeployer` will not do the task you are looking for. `

> Annotation to be used on a Spring Boot application if it wants to
>   deploy a jar file containing a function definition.

Below is example of how [Spring-Cloud-Function-Deployer](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/master/spring-cloud-function-deployer) is using this annotation.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFunctionDeployer
public class FunctionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new ApplicationBootstrap().run(FunctionApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

More info on EnableFunctionDeployer.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.RELEASE/multi/multi__deploying_a_packaged_function.html

---

Although, I cannot seem to find a `gradle` plugin which can do the deployment to AWS Lambda directly but it is easy to do it with `maven` with many plugins and ways.

One Example - [This](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/from-framework-to-function-deploying-aws-lambda-functions-for-java-8-using-apache-maven-archetype/) AWS article has maven archetype which generates a code base with [pom.xml](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-archetype/blob/master/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml) which does direct deployment to AWS Lambda(using CloudFormation in background). Below is the plugin configuration which is being used to execute `aws cloudformation` executable.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sam-local-invoke</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>sam</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>local</argument>
                    <argument>invoke</argument>
                    <argument>-e</argument>
                    <argument>event.json</argument>
                </arguments>
                <skip>${skipLocalInvoke}</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>sam-package</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>aws</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>cloudformation</argument>
                    <argument>package</argument>
                    <argument>--region=${awsRegion}</argument>
                    <argument>--template-file=template.yaml</argument>
                    <argument>--output-template-file=target/sam.yaml</argument>
                    <argument>--s3-bucket=${s3Bucket}</argument>
                    <argument>--s3-prefix=${s3Prefix}</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>sam-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>aws</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>cloudformation</argument>
                    <argument>deploy</argument>
                    <argument>--region=${awsRegion}</argument>
                    <argument>--template-file=target/sam.yaml</argument>
                    <argument>--stack-name=${stackName}</argument>
                    <argument>--capabilities=CAPABILITY_IAM</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If you insist to be on gradle, probably one of the option is to execute `maven deploy` command from gradle using [gradle-maven-exec-plugin](https://github.com/dkorotych/gradle-maven-exec-plugin)(need to test it though).

My personal opinion would be to build the jar using gradle/maven and deploy using [serverless](https://serverless.com/) framework separating the deploy & build with different tools.

Example - 
https://gist.github.com/lobster1234/201fb83dc2847a1e2a106a098636bc1f

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I also need @EnableFunctionDeployer, But I could not see any example how to implement it, is there any example that you know?

Comment: I am not able to give you the full example but [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/master/spring-cloud-function-deployer) is example of using @EnableFunctionDeployer. I have edited the answer to refer this example for future users. if you are ok with it, please accept it as  answer.

Comment: I can't imagine how to use it with  aws  lambda, which jar I need to specify for function.location?  is it other version of the same function project?
do I need to upload the jar to s3 bucket?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53452675/5030709) question. It has some clues on how to use deployer.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon provides a tool for continuous deployment called AWS CodePipeline.
You can use it on it's own to continuously deploy your application or you could migrate your function to an AWS Codestar project, it creates every resource needed for building and deploying your function.
The AWS Free tier offers one free active pipeline each month and Codestar is free, so you can check it out without incurring in any costs.